# On Azure Web App Service, sometime get Character �(#65533), but then things go back to normal,they're same page

Tags: .net, azure, azure-web-app-service

[Web Link](https://blog.miniasp.com/?page=39)

#### Problem:

On Azure Web App Service, sometime get Character �(#65533), but then things go back to normal,they're same page and it is normal under local iis server.

character �(#65533) version:

```
...這���種假物件...
```

[image]

normal version:

```
...這兩種假物件...
```

[image]

#### Environment :

Web.Config : `<globalization requestEncoding="utf-8" responseEncoding="utf-8" />`

Server : Microsoft-IIS/10.0,Asp.NET 4.5.2

FrameWork : BlogEngine.NET

#### My Question:

Is it Azure problem or some one azure setting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it related to [BlogEngine.NET](https://github.com/rxtur/BlogEngine.NET) implementation. In [CompressionModule.cs#L189](https://github.com/rxtur/BlogEngine.NET/blob/612164e60f1c47d74e8bdcdf334f8e991d16873b/BlogEngine/BlogEngine.Core/Web/HttpModules/CompressionModule.cs#L189), it configured a `WebResourceFilter` into `context.Response.Filter`. That's the root cause of this problem.

You can check the [WebResourceFilter.cs](https://github.com/rxtur/BlogEngine.NET/blob/612164e60f1c47d74e8bdcdf334f8e991d16873b/BlogEngine/BlogEngine.Core/Web/Scripting/WebResourceFilter.cs) file.  The [Write()](https://github.com/rxtur/BlogEngine.NET/blob/612164e60f1c47d74e8bdcdf334f8e991d16873b/BlogEngine/BlogEngine.Core/Web/Scripting/WebResourceFilter.cs#L286-L291) method do have problem:

```
public override void Write(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
{
    // collect all HTML in local variable
    var html = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer, offset, count);
    HtmlOut += html;
}
```

The buffer size is not guarantee. If the buffer split in the middle of the UTF-8 character (which Chinese characters in UTF-8 is multi-bytes).  It's impossible to get the right string in UTF8.  So you will get the messy characters you mentioned.

There is also an exact issue here: https://github.com/rxtur/BlogEngine.NET/issues/91